# Is there an app or program that relates anime & manga with their source material?

Tags: resources

Long story short, there are relations between literature and plays 
that are source material for anime and manga and I'm looking for an app that relates them.

Examples of such relationships are:

- The literature **["The Tale of the Princess Kaguya"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Princess_Kaguya)**

  - **Kaguya** is the same name as [the mother of chakra in Naruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
    who came from a different planet and ultimate chakra uses the moon
  - **Sailor Moon** is initially believed to be an Earthling, but is later revealed to be the princess of the moon kingdom Silver Millennium. She later discovers her birth name, Princess Serenity [moon princess aka Kaguya]
- **Journey of the West**: Dragon ball/DBZ is highly influenced by "Journey of the West" and the story of the monkey god Sun Wukong.
- **"The Tale of the Gallant Jiraiya"**: Naruto also takes from a famous story "The Tale of the Gallant Jiraiya" where Jiraiya can turn into a toad,  Orochimaru a snake, and Tsunade a slug.

Comment: Google/StartPage/DuckDuckGo?

Comment: I don't think Princess Kaguya is Sailor Moon, instead is [Princess Snow Kaguya](http://sailormoon.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Snow_Kaguya)